# Pass variable into jQuery attribute-contains selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, custom-data-attribute

Is it possible to pass a variable into a jQuery attribute-contains selector?

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-vp='{
  id: vp-485858383,
  customTwo: "test"
}'>
asdf
</div>

$(function() {
    var testString = "vp-485858383";
  $('[data-vp*="id: ${testString}"]').css('color', 'red');
});
```

I have also tried:

```
$('[data-vp*="id:' +  testString + '"]').css('color', 'red');
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/to0oq8L5/2/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you just need a space after `id:`

```
$(function() {
    var testString = "vp-485858383";
  $('[data-vp*="id: ' +  testString + '"]').css('color', 'red');
});
```

Demo

```js
$(function() {
 var testString = "vp-485858383";
  $('[data-vp*="id: ' +  testString + '"]').css('color', 'red');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-vp='{
      id: vp-485858383,
      customTwo: "test"
}'>
asdf
</div>
```

Comment: That's it. Thanks!